# UTF-8 string not displaying character properly

Tags: python-3.x

I am returning text field from DB column:

```
 "algún nombre de juego"
```

when I try to use this text in an html file, I get the following string:

```
algÃºn nombre de juego
```

This happens consistently with any string that is not pure english. I have even tried grabbing simple text from online in different languages and as soon as I plug them into an html text box, the print out with improper encoding like the example above.

From reading Unicode documentation for python, UTF-8 should be able to handle pretty much any character in any language.

I have tried many ways of encoding/decoding, and either there is an encoding error, or I get back weird character where the letter u with acute should be.

Per comments, I am not using Django or Flask. Just taking strings from a DB that might be in several different languages and generating an HTML file for internal use.

Comment: HTML is not python. You need to convert the unicode characters to their HTML-entity equivalent (`ú` becomes `&uacute;`)

Comment: @PranavHosangadi, am I correct to think that I need to pass a python string that is meant to be HTML through BeautifulSoup or something similar to make the conversion? Or is there a better approach?

Comment: @kravb It might be a good idea to also tag this question with the framework that you're (such as Django or Flask) using in order to get some more answers.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few ideas:

**1. Remember to declare the encoding.** Either:

- Insert a `<meta charset="utf-8">` just after your `<head>` tag.

  OR
- do this in the HTTP header (making it look something like `Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8`). This can be done by changing the webserver's settings or using server-side code, should you choose to host the page.

**2. Ensure that your IDE saves files as UTF-8.** This will be somewhere in your settings and should be done automatically, but worth checking if option 1 doesn't work.

Hope one of these works.